Forces on a fluid contained in a U- tube
I have a U- tube filled with the same fluid (which is incompressible) upto a height h on both sides. This is my initial configuration.  If I displace the fluid on one of the sides of the U- tube by a distance x as shown in the figure, and i release it, intuitively the system returns to the initial configuration.
But what force is responsible for making it return to the initial configuration? If I look at the system with displaced fluid, there is atmospheric pressure acting on surfaces on both sides. Area of cross section of both limbs of the U- tube is assumed to be the same. Clearly, external force due to atmosphere on this system cancels out. Now, what's the force which acts "along the U-tube" and brings the fluid back to the initial condition.

The restoring force is the weight of the fluid.

Can we find the expression for restoring force acting along the tube?

If you draw a horizontal line across the U-tube at level $h-x$, it should become clear that everything below the line is symmetrically distributed and that a plug of liquid with height $2x$ above the line is pushing down with its weight.

Can we find the expression for restoring force acting along the tube?
The restoring force is due to the difference in pressures on either side of the connecting tube which in turn is due to the difference in head heights on either side.
Let d be the height of the joining tube. The pressure at the mid height (d/2) of the joining tube on a given side is due to column of liquid in the vertical tube on that side is given by $P = p (h-d/2) g$ where p is the density of the fluid and g is the acceleration of gravity. The force on a given side is proportional to the pressure and the cross sectional area (A) of the joining tube, so $F = PA$. If $F_L$ is the force on the left and $F_R$ is the force on the right, the restoring force is $$\Delta F = F_L - F_R = A (P_L-P_R) = pA (h_L-h_R)g$$
